# save data into the txt file ? C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm creating a program in which user enter mcqs and option and then save the data into the `txt` file.How can i do this .I try but it's not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    std::string fname;
    cout<<"Enter file name";
    std::getline (std::cin,fname);
    outputFile.open(fname+".txt");
    std::string name;
    std::string mcqs;
    int x;
    cout<<"How many questions want \n";
    cin>>x;

    for(int i=1;i<=x;i=i+1){
        cout<"Enter question "+i;
        std::getline (std::cin,name);
        outputFile << name << endl;
        cout<<"Option A";
        std::getline (std::cin,mcqs);
        outputFile << mcqs << endl;
        cout<<"Option B";
        std::getline (std::cin,mcqs);
        outputFile << mcqs << endl;
        cout<<"Option C";
        std::getline (std::cin,mcqs);
        outputFile << mcqs << endl;
        cout<<"Option D";
        std::getline (std::cin,mcqs);
        outputFile << mcqs << endl;
    }

    outputFile.close();
    cout << "Done!\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I want save `mcqs` and option in `txt` file.Thanks

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Also your code formatting should have a serious overworking.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with cin to get question numbers. You can use get_line and stringstream to read numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    std::string fname;
    std::string str;
    stringstream ss;
    int x;

    cout<<"Enter file name:";
    std::getline (std::cin,fname);
    outputFile.open(fname+".txt");

    cout<<"How many questions want \n";
    std::getline (std::cin,str);
    ss << str;
    ss >> x;
    if (x == 0)
        cout << "Invalid question number...!" << endl;

    for(int i=1;i<=x;i=i+1){
            cout<<"Enter question " << i << ":";
            std::getline (std::cin,str);
            outputFile << str << endl;

            cout<<"Option A:";
            std::getline (std::cin,str);
            outputFile << str << endl;

            cout<<"Option B:";
            std::getline (std::cin,str);
            outputFile << str << endl;

            cout<<"Option C:";
            std::getline (std::cin,str);
            outputFile << str << endl;

            cout<<"Option D:";
            std::getline (std::cin,str);
            outputFile << str << endl;
    }

    outputFile.close();
    cout << "Done!\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include  at the top and ofstream is a member of namespace std.